# Mime Type Not Being Set Correctly

Tags: java, xml, soap

I am trying to call a SOAP API over HTTP and I need advices. The problem is that when I set the property to say the content type should be "text/xml" it is not setting it:

```
    URL url = new URL(SOAP_URI);

    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept","text/xml charset=utf-8");
    System.out.println(con.getContentType());
```

When I print out con.getContentType it prints out:

```
    text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

How can I set it to text/xml charset=utf-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`con.getContentType` returns the value of the *Content-Type* header field of **URL resource**, while `setRequestProperty("Accept")` changes the property of the *Accept* header of the **request**.

Try `getRequestProperty` to get the *Accept* header of the request:

```
System.out.println(con.getRequestProperty("Accept"));
```

To set and print the `Content-Type` header of the request:

```
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
System.out.println(con.getRequestProperty("Content-Type"));
```